How to add the extension pg_squeeze to shared_preload_libraries in Azure Postgres?
I am trying to enable pg_squeeze on a Azure Postgres instance. I have successfully enabled it in the azure extensions. However, when I go to add it to the shared_preload_libraries I get the following error after the deployment fails:

The value 'pg_availability,pg_cron,pg_stat_statements,pg_squeeze' for configuration 'shared_preload_libraries' is not valid. The allowed values are 'the ones indicated by PostgreSQL documentation'. (Code: InvalidConfigurationValue)

I have tried this several times with no success. I am selecting the value out of the drop down, and it is available to pick in the list. Why would this be occurring and how do I fix it?
Here is the list you pick from in Azure, it is obviously there available to add.


Are the tildes literally present in the message, or is that your attempt to censor some information?

@jjanes i was just censoring out the other extensions. I guess the list really doesn't matter. I will put the real list back in.

This seems like an azure-specific problem.  There might be a better way of getting MS attention than posting here.  If you set up a test instance that only has pg_squeeze in the list, does that work?

It's an azure portal issue. Just ran into the same problem, but it works fine when you use the CLI.
az postgres flexible-server parameter set --resource-group <resource_group>  --server-name <server> --subscription <subscription_id> --name shared_preload_libraries --value pg_availability,pg_cron,pg_stat_statements,pg_squeeze


Not all extensions are compatible with all PostgreSQL versions, and this might cause issues.
You can verify the installation with:
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions WHERE name = 'pg_squeeze';
The value for for shared_preload_libraries
The value should be a comma-separated list of extensions, with no extra spaces or invalid characters. e.g. (pg_squeeze,other_extension)
If none of the above steps resolve the issue reach out to Azure support. They Providewith detailed information about your PostgreSQL version, the exact error message.

I get back this:
|name|default_version|installed_version|comment|
|----|---------------|-----------------|-------|
|pg_squeeze|1.6||A tool to remove unused space from a relation.|

It would seem that you (or Azures interface!) enclosed multiple libraries together in quotes, like a single string. (Single or double quotes result in the same error here.)
Lose the enclosing quotes when setting the GUC parameter, and it should work. Like:
SET shared_preload_libraries TO pg_stat_statements, auto_explain, pg_squeeze;

Not:
SET shared_preload_libraries TO 'pg_stat_statements, auto_explain, pg_squeeze';
Same applies to the postgresql.conf file or other ways to set it.
Quotes are only used for individual libraries (if necessary). The manual:

Whitespace between entries is ignored; surround a library name with double quotes if you need to include whitespace or commas in the name.

Note the subtle syntax difference: LOAD actually requires a single-quoted string parameter as library name - actually a filename or a whole path. Different context.

Those quotes came from the error message that Azure logged. You have no control over how to set those values. You have to do it through the Azure UI. I will add a picture of the UI that controls that setting.

@SpaceGhost440: Then it would seem Azure's interface messes up the string. The error msg speaks of a single value, where it should be multiple values. Either way, you'll have to bring this up with Azure / MS ...
